# Find median of a combination of tables.

Tags: statistics, average, median

Values in List $P$ are distinct from values in List $Q$. List $R$ consists of all the values in list $P$ and all the values in list $Q$.

[image: Tables P and Q]

Find the median of list $R$.

My logic:
Here the total number of elements is $100$, which implies that the median is the average of the $50^{\text{th}}$ and $51^{\text{st}}$ elements. So, according to me that should be $\frac{6+6}{2} = 6$. However the answer is $5.5$.

What confuses me is that the question specifies that elements in $P$ are distinct from elements in $Q$, and an answer of $5.5$ can be achieved only if we consider the $5$'s and $6$'s of both the tables to be same!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $50$ elements of $R$ that are $5$ or below:  $44$ from $P$ and $6$ from $Q$.  There are also $50$ elements of $R$ that are $6$ or above:  $16$ from $P$ and $34$ from $Q$.  The median is halfway between $5$ and $6$, or $5.5$.  The statement that the items are distinct means that $R$ has $16$ items in the $5$ bin because we can add $10+6$.  If some of the items were the same we would have to deduct the matches from $16$.

Comment: @Henry:  $12+13+9+10=44$  For $5$ or below you need to count the $10$ that are in the $5$ bin as $5$ or below.  There are $34$ that are strictly below $5$, but that is not what we want.

Comment: My mistake - As a shortcut I had thought there were $50$ in each set and $16$ in list P above $5$